# Need to load an html page in the center column (of a three column layout) when a link is clicked in the left column

Tags: jquery, html, css

This functionality works in a separate project (just not in my three column layout) and I'm wondering if I'm suppressing the 'load' by something that I've done in my css.

I've posted this on jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/FhpE7/8/

Answer (score -1):

You can use an iframe in the center column and have your links on the left target it.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: The links are loading various html pages when they're utilized in another project. The problem lies in getting them to load an html page in the current layout.